# How to align a UILabel to a corner of a UIViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, user-interface, interface-builder

I have a simple UIViewController and would like to add a label which is always shown in the exact bottom-left of the view, regardless of the device's size. I've tried playing around with the constraints but can't seem to make any progress.

Even if I select both the view and the label the "Leading Edges" constraints stay grey. I am using the center constraint fine w/o any issues, so hoping to find something similar.

Ideally I would do this without writing any code, but if it is absolutely necessary I am open to it.

Comment: Add "Leading space to container" and "Bottom space to container" constraint **and** set a static height and width for your label.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I tried what Nikolausindra said which was your suggestion w/o the static height and width and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By ctrl+drag from UILabel to UIView underneath it and select "Leading space to container" and "Bottom space to container" constraint.

Answer (score 2):

When adding constraints, you must add enough constraints that xcode can figure out an x position, y position, height, and width.  Add a height and width constraint, and select the red lines for bottom and left constraints.  Click the arrow next to the values, and make sure the view is selected, and set the values however you want.  Set update frames to update frames with new constraints, and hit add.